# semPlot package Rstudio

Tags: r, statistics, semplot

I have been having trouble with the r package "**semPlot**" successfully installing onto `Rstudio 1.2.5033`

Each time I have tried installing the `semplot` package I get the following error.

```
install.packages('semPlot')
library(semPlot)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘semPlot’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘data.table’

I have tried installing the package that is being called to not be there (in the above case '`data.table`'), but I have done this 5 or 6 times and feeling like continuous this process is insanity.

Alternatively, is there any alternative to reviewing the path diagrams from SEM if the `semPlot` package (for the `semPaths` function) continues this process?

Comment: I think installing `data.table` library will solve your issue. After that again install `semPlot`

Comment: Hi @MMoore93, I am on R 3.6.1 and could install and load semPlot.. do you get any error when loading data.table? Or is data.table located in your library path? "data.table" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) ; is that TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your installer not with semPlot. Try

```
install.packages('semPlot', dependencies = T)
```

would be helpful if you mention your OS

Comment: Thanks @Cauliflower. Works like a charm now!